# How to have multiple outputs with AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `AVCaptureSession` with `Vision` to recognize people faces with the camera. I'm adding an output (`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`) to my `AVCaptureSession` instance to take the image frames and detect faces on them. The problem is: I want to make a video recording with the faces detected (with something over the detected faces). I'm trying to use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` but when I add an instance of this class as an output of my `AVCaptureSession` instance, the app crash because more of two outputs are not allowed on an `AVCaptureSession`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that is not possible to use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` as outputs for `AVCaptureSession` at the same time.